# New install of Fenics demo crashes on MPICH_NUMVERSION

Tags: python, c++, linux, mpi, petsc

I am trying to run a basic demo from Fenics (2016.2.0) on Ubuntu 16.04.2, Python 2.7, Anaconda (with Spyder for the IDE). The demo is `ft_01poisson.py`. The error says:

```
RuntimeError: In instant.recompile: The module did not compile with command 'make VERBOSE=1', see '.../error/dolfin_6c..dc/compile.log'
```

Ok, let's take a look. Everything is fine until...

```
.../anaconda2/include/petscsys.h:144:6: error: #error "PETSc was configured with MPICH but now appears to be compiling using a non-MPICH mpi.h"
#    error "PETSc was configured with MPICH but now appears to be compiling using a non-MPICH mpi.h"
```

Ok, let's see what the source says:

```
#elif defined(PETSC_HAVE_MPICH_NUMVERSION)
#  if !defined(MPICH_NUMVERSION)
#    error "PETSc was configured with MPICH but now appears to be compiling using a non-MPICH mpi.h"
```

I track down `~/anaconda2/include/petscconf.h`:

```
#define PETSC_HAVE_MPICH_NUMVERSION 30200300
```

Now, the version of `~/anaconda2/include/mpi.h` that I have in  is version 2.2, but I have another version of `mpi.h` in a `mpich-3.2.4 install` which does have the correct `MPICH_NUMVERSION`.

I tried a simple copy and paste of the relevant files and `#include`s to the `~/anaconda2/include/` folder to no avail (the first error is `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]`).

So how do I fix this? How do I get the demo to run after following the instructions to install Fenics?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is to work within the FenicsProject Environment as suggested by

```
conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics
```

I would delete my own question, but I don't know how. Enjoy everyone!

Comment: Just below your question is a link that says `delete`.  If you want to delete your question, then click it!